# I can't boot after upgrading glibc... how can I rebuild my ld.so cache?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, glibc, kernel-panic, ld

Hello Unix StackExchange!

I unfortunately made a huge mistake. I needed a newer version of `glibc` on my system for a screensharing application, so I ran the following commands to download and build `glibc 2.37` locally:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.37.tar.gz
tar -xvf glibc-2.37.tar.gz
cd glib-2.37
mkdir make
mkdir /opt/glibc-2.37
../configure --prfix=/opt/glibc-2.37
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Then, I created a file called `new-glibc.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` with the following content:

```
# New glibc version for venmic
/opt/glibc-2.37/lib
```

Then, I ran `sudo ldconfig` and got `Segmentation fault` after every command I could possibly type. My applications stopped launching and nothing would work, so I shut down my Linux Mint system. Upon rebooting, I can only see the Linux Mint logo and nothing happens.

So, I boot into recovery mode using the GRUB menu, and I see this:
[image]

A kernel panic. Great.

So, I boot into my system using a live CD and delete `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/new-glibc.conf`. But unfortunately, nothing changed: I'm still getting a kernel panic for the same reason because my system is still trying to boot with the `/opt/glibc-2.37` libraries.

Please help! I'm using the latest version of Linux Mint and the previous version of `glibc` (the one that came with my system) is 2.35. I suspect the only way to fix this is by rebuilding the ld.so cache from scratch by running `ldconfig` again, but how would I do that if I can't boot into the system or enter recovery mode?

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by doing a Timeshift restore on my system from Live CD. Thank god the restore was only from 20 minutes before the crash.